# Replace quotations, period, forward slash and all letters using regex

Tags: javascript, regex, string

How can I use regex to replace all the characters in a string that are either alphabetic, a forward slash, a period or double quotations?

I am able to do letters:

```
"abcd123/./"".replace(/([^\x00-\x80]|\w)/g, "someReplacementText"));
```

Comment: How about: `[a-zA-Z\/."]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just place all the characters you want into a non-negated character set:

```
/[a-zA-Z\/\.\"]/g
```